# user xmlrpc to call API using PHP

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I want to use XMLRPC to call API using PHP to realize the login function. Java method is posted as follows. **How to realize the same function using PHP?** Thank you.

```
public void testLogin() 
{
    Proxy proxy = null;
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("realmId", "12345"); // AD id/password

    try {

        proxy = ProxyFactory.createProxy("SimpleFactory");
        ModifyUser modUser = new ModifyUser("ActiveDirectory","","ADuserid");
        modUser.assignRealm("12345", null, null);
        proxy.getUpdateSvc().execute(admSession.getSessionToken(), modUser, new HashMap());
        AuthResultTO result = proxy.getAuthnSvc().login("", "ADuserid", "password", params);
        assertTrue(result.getSession().isAuthenticated());
        String sessionToken = result.getSession().getSessionToken();

    } catch (XmlRpcException e) {

        fail(e.code + "," +e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        proxy.close();
    }
}
```